# Can't understand basic algebra behind transfer function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Im having trouble understanding the algebra behind what is in the red box. I just can't grasp how -Vo(s) was brought to the left side and how the result written in blue was obtained.

Can someone help me understand?

[image: Transfer function]

Comment: Post on http://electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: I did that and they sent me here.. Because its really just an algebra problem.

Comment: This post has little to do with electronics besides the variables, it's all basic algebra they are asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\dfrac{V_i (s)}{R_1} = - V_o (s) \left(\dfrac{R_2 C s + 1}{R_2}\right)$$

Dividing both sides by $V_i (s)$,

$$\dfrac{1}{R_1} = - \dfrac{V_o (s)}{V_i (s)} \left(\dfrac{R_2 C s + 1}{R_2}\right)$$

Multiplying both sides by $-R_1$,

$$-1 = \dfrac{V_o (s)}{V_i (s)} \dfrac{R_1}{R_2} (R_2 C s + 1)$$

Thus,

$$\dfrac{V_o (s)}{V_i (s)} =  -\dfrac{R_2}{R_1} \left(\dfrac{1}{R_2 C s + 1}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

You have:
$$
V_1=-R_1V_0\left(\frac{1}{R_2}+sC \right)
$$
so:
$$
\frac{V_0}{V_1}=\frac{-1}{R_1\frac{1+R_2sC}{R_2}}=-\frac{R_2}{R_1}\frac{1}{1+R_2sC}
$$